# Using central limit theorem to prove most of an n dimensional cube is contained in a given annulus

Tags: central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Let x = (x1, . . . , xn) ∈ $R^n$

Let ||x|| := $\sqrt{(x_1^2 + . . . + x_n^2)}$

Let ε > 0.

Show that for all
sufficiently large n, “most” of the cube [−1, 1]$^n$
is contained in the annulus

A := $(x ∈ R^n : (1-\epsilon)\sqrt{n/3}\le||x||\le(1+\epsilon)\sqrt{n/3})$

That is, if X1, . . . , Xn are each independent and identically distributed in [−1, 1], then for n
sufficiently large
P((X1, . . . , Xn) ∈ A) ≥ 1 − ε.

(Hint: apply the weak law of large numbers to $X_1^2, X_2^2 ...$)

I have absolutely no idea how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Write down what the law of large numbers implies for $X_1^2,X_2^2,\ldots$.

> $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \overset{p}{\to} \mathbb{E} X_1^2 = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Then note that the condition defining the annulus $A$ can be rewritten as follows.
\begin{align}
(1-\epsilon)\sqrt{n/3} \le \|X\| \le (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{n/3}
\\
(1-\epsilon)^2/3
\le \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2
\le (1+\epsilon)^2/3
\end{align}

Comment: And so then you replace the middle term in A with 1/3, multiple outside terms by 3, and take square root to get $(1-\epsilon)\le 1 \le (1+\epsilon)$? Is that enough to solve the proof?

Comment: @Adam You should be more formal and work with the definition of "convergence in probability" when applying the law of large numbers.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this now. I guess if you subtract 1/3 from them all, the limit of the middle goes to 0 by LoLN, the left bound becomes some constant less than 0 and the right bound becomes some constant greater than 0. Therefore the probability that 0 is between a negative and positive value = 1, which is what we wanted.